# build errors when upgrade postsharp from 4.2.25 to 4.3.48

Tags: c#, postsharp

I am very new to postsharp. In our project we are using postsharp C# to develop a web service. When we try to upgrade postsharp from 4.2.25 to 4.3.48, I encounter the below issues:

```
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: Unhandled exception (4.3.48.0, postsharp-net40-x86-srv.exe, CLR 4.0.30319.528372, Release): PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.AssemblyLoadException: Cannot find assembly 'mysql.data, version=6.9.8.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=null'. [Public key mismatch]
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: ============ PostSharp Assembly Loading Log ===================
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Finding the assembly with binding identity 'mysql.data, version=6.9.8.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=c5687fc88969c44d'.
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Found file 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\MySql.Data.6.9.8\lib\net40\MySql.Data.dll' with identity 'mysql.data, version=0.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=null, processorarchitecture=msil'.
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Reference mismatch for 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\MySql.Data.6.9.8\lib\net40\MySql.Data.dll' [PublicKeyMismatch].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'C:\ProgramData\PostSharp\4.3.48\bin.Release\MySql.Data.exe' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'C:\ProgramData\PostSharp\4.3.48\bin.Release\MySql.Data.dll' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'C:\ProgramData\PostSharp\4.3.48\bin.Release\MySql.Data.winmd' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\Raas.Assets.Data\bin\Debug\MySql.Data.exe' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Found file 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\Raas.Assets.Data\bin\Debug\MySql.Data.dll' with identity 'mysql.data, version=0.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=null, processorarchitecture=msil'.
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Reference mismatch for 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\Raas.Assets.Data\bin\Debug\MySql.Data.dll' [PublicKeyMismatch].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\Raas.Assets.Data\bin\Debug\MySql.Data.winmd' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\Raas.Assets.Data\obj\Debug\MySql.Data.exe' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\Raas.Assets.Data\obj\Debug\MySql.Data.dll' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\Raas.Assets.Data\obj\Debug\MySql.Data.winmd' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\Autodesk360-API-SDK-RAAS.1.1.3\lib\net452\MySql.Data.exe' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\Autodesk360-API-SDK-RAAS.1.1.3\lib\net452\MySql.Data.dll' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\Autodesk360-API-SDK-RAAS.1.1.3\lib\net452\MySql.Data.winmd' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\AWSSDK.CloudFront.3.3.104.13\lib\net45\MySql.Data.exe' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\AWSSDK.CloudFront.3.3.104.13\lib\net45\MySql.Data.dll' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\AWSSDK.CloudFront.3.3.104.13\lib\net45\MySql.Data.winmd' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\AWSSDK.CloudSearchDomain.3.3.100.134\lib\net45\MySql.Data.exe' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\AWSSDK.CloudSearchDomain.3.3.100.134\lib\net45\MySql.Data.dll' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\AWSSDK.CloudSearchDomain.3.3.100.134\lib\net45\MySql.Data.winmd' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\AWSSDK.CloudWatch.3.3.108.11\lib\net45\MySql.Data.exe' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\AWSSDK.CloudWatch.3.3.108.11\lib\net45\MySql.Data.dll' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\AWSSDK.CloudWatch.3.3.108.11\lib\net45\MySql.Data.winmd' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\AWSSDK.Core.3.3.107.40\lib\net45\MySql.Data.exe' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\AWSSDK.Core.3.3.107.40\lib\net45\MySql.Data.dll' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\AWSSDK.Core.3.3.107.40\lib\net45\MySql.Data.winmd' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\AWSSDK.EC2.3.3.201.1\lib\net45\MySql.Data.exe' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\AWSSDK.EC2.3.3.201.1\lib\net45\MySql.Data.dll' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\AWSSDK.EC2.3.3.201.1\lib\net45\MySql.Data.winmd' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\AWSSDK.IdentityManagement.3.3.106.34\lib\net45\MySql.Data.exe' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\AWSSDK.IdentityManagement.3.3.106.34\lib\net45\MySql.Data.dll' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\AWSSDK.IdentityManagement.3.3.106.34\lib\net45\MySql.Data.winmd' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\AWSSDK.S3.3.3.113.2\lib\net45\MySql.Data.exe' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\AWSSDK.S3.3.3.113.2\lib\net45\MySql.Data.dll' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\AWSSDK.S3.3.3.113.2\lib\net45\MySql.Data.winmd' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\AWSSDK.SecretsManager.3.3.101.84\lib\net45\MySql.Data.exe' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\AWSSDK.SecretsManager.3.3.101.84\lib\net45\MySql.Data.dll' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\AWSSDK.SecretsManager.3.3.101.84\lib\net45\MySql.Data.winmd' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\AWSSDK.SimpleNotificationService.3.3.102.17\lib\net45\MySql.Data.exe' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\AWSSDK.SimpleNotificationService.3.3.102.17\lib\net45\MySql.Data.dll' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\AWSSDK.SimpleNotificationService.3.3.102.17\lib\net45\MySql.Data.winmd' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\AWSSDK.SQS.3.3.103.26\lib\net45\MySql.Data.exe' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\AWSSDK.SQS.3.3.103.26\lib\net45\MySql.Data.dll' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\AWSSDK.SQS.3.3.103.26\lib\net45\MySql.Data.winmd' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\Castle.Core.3.2.0\lib\net45\MySql.Data.exe' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\Castle.Core.3.2.0\lib\net45\MySql.Data.dll' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\Castle.Core.3.2.0\lib\net45\MySql.Data.winmd' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\Castle.LoggingFacility.3.2.0\lib\net45\MySql.Data.exe' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\Castle.LoggingFacility.3.2.0\lib\net45\MySql.Data.dll' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\Castle.LoggingFacility.3.2.0\lib\net45\MySql.Data.winmd' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\Castle.Windsor.3.2.0\lib\net45\MySql.Data.exe' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\Castle.Windsor.3.2.0\lib\net45\MySql.Data.dll' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\Castle.Windsor.3.2.0\lib\net45\MySql.Data.winmd' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\Clic.Sdk.NET.1.6.6.81\lib\net452\MySql.Data.exe' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\Clic.Sdk.NET.1.6.6.81\lib\net452\MySql.Data.dll' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\Clic.Sdk.NET.1.6.6.81\lib\net452\MySql.Data.winmd' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\DotNetOpenAuth.dll.4.1.0\lib\net452\MySql.Data.exe' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\DotNetOpenAuth.dll.4.1.0\lib\net452\MySql.Data.dll' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\DotNetOpenAuth.dll.4.1.0\lib\net452\MySql.Data.winmd' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\MySql.Data.exe' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\MySql.Data.dll' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\MySql.Data.winmd' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\EntityFramework.Extended.6.1.0.168\lib\net45\MySql.Data.exe' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\EntityFramework.Extended.6.1.0.168\lib\net45\MySql.Data.dll' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\EntityFramework.Extended.6.1.0.168\lib\net45\MySql.Data.winmd' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll.0.85.4.369\lib\net20\MySql.Data.exe' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll.0.85.4.369\lib\net20\MySql.Data.dll' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll.0.85.4.369\lib\net20\MySql.Data.winmd' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\Iesi.Collections.1.0.1\lib\MySql.Data.exe' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\Iesi.Collections.1.0.1\lib\MySql.Data.dll' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\Iesi.Collections.1.0.1\lib\MySql.Data.winmd' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\DotNetZip.1.9.1.8\lib\net20\MySql.Data.exe' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\DotNetZip.1.9.1.8\lib\net20\MySql.Data.dll' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\DotNetZip.1.9.1.8\lib\net20\MySql.Data.winmd' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\jose-jwt.3.2.0\lib\net461\MySql.Data.exe' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\jose-jwt.3.2.0\lib\net461\MySql.Data.dll' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\jose-jwt.3.2.0\lib\net461\MySql.Data.winmd' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\JWT.8.2.0\lib\net46\MySql.Data.exe' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\JWT.8.2.0\lib\net46\MySql.Data.dll' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\JWT.8.2.0\lib\net46\MySql.Data.winmd' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\log4net.2.0.12\lib\net45\MySql.Data.exe' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\log4net.2.0.12\lib\net45\MySql.Data.dll' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\log4net.2.0.12\lib\net45\MySql.Data.winmd' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\MySql.Data.exe' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\MySql.Data.dll' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\MySql.Data.winmd' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.5.3.0\lib\net461\MySql.Data.exe' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.5.3.0\lib\net461\MySql.Data.dll' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.5.3.0\lib\net461\MySql.Data.winmd' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.5.3.0\lib\net461\MySql.Data.exe' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.5.3.0\lib\net461\MySql.Data.dll' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.5.3.0\lib\net461\MySql.Data.winmd' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.5.3.0\lib\net461\MySql.Data.exe' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.5.3.0\lib\net461\MySql.Data.dll' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.5.3.0\lib\net461\MySql.Data.winmd' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Async.1.0.168\lib\net40\MySql.Data.exe' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Async.1.0.168\lib\net40\MySql.Data.dll' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Async.1.0.168\lib\net40\MySql.Data.winmd' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0\lib\net40\MySql.Data.exe' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0\lib\net40\MySql.Data.dll' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0\lib\net40\MySql.Data.winmd' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\mongocsharpdriver.1.6\lib\net35\MySql.Data.exe' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\mongocsharpdriver.1.6\lib\net35\MySql.Data.dll' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\mongocsharpdriver.1.6\lib\net35\MySql.Data.winmd' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\Mono.Math.dll.4.0.2\lib\net452\MySql.Data.exe' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\Mono.Math.dll.4.0.2\lib\net452\MySql.Data.dll' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\Mono.Math.dll.4.0.2\lib\net452\MySql.Data.winmd' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
1>POSTSHARP : postsharp error PS0099: LOG: Probing location 'D:\GEC\aes360\venus\packages\MySql.Data.6.9.8\lib\net40\MySql.Data.exe' because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
```

Does anyone happen to know the possible cause? Do you know how to resolve it? Does postsharp depend on MySQL and mySQL version does not match postsharp? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

PostSharp 4.3 is no longer supported and it may contain bugs fixed in later versions. The latest supported version is 6.10. For details on PostSharp lifecycle, see https://www.postsharp.net/support/policies#support. Upgrading of PostSharp is documented at https://doc.postsharp.net/upgrade.